# Failure of Tomiyama's property ($F$) for reduced group $C^*$-algebras

Tags: gr.group-theory, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Are there known examples of discrete groups such that the minimal tensor product of their reduced group $C^\ast$-algebras does not have Tomiyama's property ($F$)?
Such groups must necessarily be non-exact, and also cannot be $C^\ast$-simple.

Two $C^\ast$-algebras $A$ and $B$ are said to have Tomiyama's property ($F$) if every closed ideal in their minimal tensor product is the closure of the sum of ideals of the form $I \otimes J$, where $I$ is a closed ideal in $A$, and $J$ is a closed ideal in $B$. Defined on page 223 in
Tomiyama (1967) # Applications of Fubini type theorem to the tensor products of $C^\ast$-algebras [Tohoku Math. J., II. Ser. 19],
a reference with several equivalent statements to Tomiyama's property ($F$) is Section 2.8 of
Blanchard, Kirchberg (2004) # Non-simple purely infinite $C^\ast$-algebras- The Hausdorff case [J. Funct. Anal. 207].

Comment: What is property (F)?

Comment: @CalebEckhardt I was also not familiar with this, but some looking online indicates that this goes back to Tomiyama's 1967 paper "Applications of Fubini type theorems to the tensor product of $C^\ast$-algebras". It would be helful if the OP could indicate their source

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have updated the original post with a definition and a reference to where it was defined.